# Exoplayer controls not working with Android 13 in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer2.x, flutter-method-channel

I have a native player, Exoplayer to be specific and I'm taking its view to flutter via method channel but I'm encountering an issue where the player works perfectly fine with lower versions of Android like 11 but in Android 13 the controls of the player don't work like pause, resume full screen.  I don't if its a problem with Exoplayer or how Flutter is using it (might be a platform-specific issue)

Comment: well i think they are aware of this bug, https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/398. I hope they fix it.